# array.map() not returning a single array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have the code below which I expect to map the result from the nested array and return a single array having both id's but I get 2 arrays instead. Can someone please guide me on what I'm doing wrongly?

```js
arrayVal = [{
    sources: {
      data: [{
        id: 1
      }]
    }
  },
  {
    sources: {
      data: [{
        id: 2
      }]
    }
  }
]

for (let sub of arrayVal) {
  let result = sub.sources.data.map(x => (x.id))
  console.log(result)
}
```

Comment: "_I get 2 arrays instead_" No you don't, you get a single array twice.

Comment: This may help: [Merge/flatten an array of arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLonowski

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following

```js
var arrayVal = [{sources: {data: [{id: 1}]}},{sources: {data: [{id: 2}]}}];

// Create an array on sources.data and merge it into 1 collection (array)
var result = arrayVal.reduce((a, c) => [...a, ...c.sources.data.map(({id}) => id)], []);

console.log(result);
```

For reference, [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Also, you can improve your code as follows

```js
var arrayVal = [{sources: {data: [{id: 1}]}},{sources: {data: [{id: 2}]}}];

let result = [];
for (let sub of arrayVal) {
  result.push(sub.sources.data.map(x => (x.id)));
}
console.log([].concat(...result))
```

Answer (score 4):

Right now, you're calling `map` for *each* element in `arrayVal`, so you get two arrays. Use `reduce` instead, to transform an array of objects into another array *that's not necessarily one-to-one* with the input elements:

```js
const arrayVal=[{sources:{data:[{id:1}]}},{sources:{data:[{id:2}]}}];

const result = arrayVal.reduce((a, { sources: { data } }) => (
  [...a, ...data.map(({ id }) => id)]
), []);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
arrayVal = [{
    sources: {
      data: [{
        id: 1
      }]
    }
  },
  {
    sources: {
      data: [{
        id: 2
      }]
    }
  }
]

let result = [];
for (let sub of arrayVal) {
  result = result.concat(sub.sources.data.map(x => (x.id)))

}

console.log(result)
```

I think `concat` is what you were missing here, Hope this is what you trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
arrayVal = [{
    sources: {
      data: [{
        id: 1
      }]
    }
  },
  {
    sources: {
      data: [{
        id: 2
      }]
    }
  }
]

let result = arrayVal.map((x) => x.sources.data[0].id)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: This does not work if `data` has more than one element.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
arrayVal = [{
    sources: {
      data: [{
        id: 1
      }]
    }
  },
  {
    sources: {
      data: [{
        id: 2
      }]
    }
  }
]

var flat = arrayVal.reduce(function(prev,curr,cI){
  prev.push(curr.sources.data.map(x => (x.id))[0]);
  return prev; // *********  Important ******
}, []);
```